# redhat yum heartbeat

Tags: linux

I'n newby with linux and I'm learning on LINUX heartbeat. I'm trying to do
"yum install heartbeat" which shows me like below...

```
# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

# yum install heartbeat
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package heartbeat available.
Nothing to do
#
```

Centos on my local does work. Can anyone explain me why redhat doesn't work and what i should do?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck asking this over at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat EL does not come with EPEL configured by default. See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F.

In your case, install http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/epel-release.html and repeat your command.

Answer (score 1):

you can get heatbeat from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ) repository

for 32bits

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
```

replace i386 with x86_64 for 64bits

Comment: How can one check if heartbeat did install after entering the command above?